# How does webserver handle HTTP POST

Tags: php, jsp, http, servlets, webserver

This might be a very basic question. But, the question that I am trying to address is that Webserver is there to handle `HTTP` Requests, So it's fully capable of handling `HTTP verbs` such as `GET`, `POST` etc.

With `GET` we are returning the request that the user is requesting. So web server can return the resource back to the user. But when it comes to `POST`, the static results can not be returned. `POST` is supposed to be dynamic. In this case, without the help of an application server, how does the webserver alone serve post requests. because the result needs to be generated dynamically which the webserver is not capable of. however, the basic purpose of the webserver is to support HTTP protocol. Therefore it should be capable of supporting HTTP POST as well.  Could anybody share some light on this to clarify this doubt

Comment: Unclear what you are asking, The response the server returns for a POST request can be anything ...

Comment: I have no idea what the question is :) Give us a clue. You appreciate a web server recevies POST requests and doesn't serve them? Try something like [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)) to get you started.

Comment: If you post data to index.php, then index.php gets the post data and can do what it wants with it.  The websever has handled the http connection and delivered the data.

Comment: Hope this http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp helps you

Comment: my questions is basically, HTTP POST is dynamic by nature. how does web server which can return only static page server POST request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the HTTP server.

Python's `SimpleHTTPServer` / `http.server` are designed to handle static files only. They do not handle anything but `GET` and `HEAD`, and will respond with `501 Unsupported method`.

If you start `nginx`, and do not specify a CGI/FastCGI/uWSGI handler, you'll get `405 Not Allowed` for most methods other than `HEAD`/`GET`, except `403 Forbidden` for `POST`.

Finally, some servers might silently (and incorrectly) respond the same way they'd respond to `GET`.

Comment: Thanks god, you got my question. I don't know why someone down voted my question

Comment: I think it is fair to say that calling oneself a HTTP Server w/o the ability to handle POST requests is a misnomer. May be in the starting days of web, serving static content was all what mattered.